Attempting to access the "Shortcuts" gallery insists I connect to the Internet, but I already am connected
I want to use the Shortcuts app on macOS 14.5. Currently, it is completely empty. When I click on the "Gallery" option on the left side of the app, I get a panel telling me to "Connect to the Internet in order to access the Gallery".  Of course, as should be clear from the fact that I'm posting this question here, I am connected to the Internet. It gives me a button to click that opens up System Settings at the "Appearance" panel, which makes no sense to me.
What is going on? What do I need to do to allow this app to be useful?

Is this a work computer or do you run some kind of VPN software?

Not a work computer, no VPN.

Thank you for your answer. If you use a different network (for example, a phone's hotspot), do you still see the error?
